# Defining named parameter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a To Do List app and I have an error with creating a Floating Action Button
There is one error message saying "The named parameter floatingActionButton is not defined"
My current code surrounding the problem is:

```
class _NewTaskState extends State<NewTask> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TaskDesc.length == 0 ? dynamicTextField : result,
                  Task.length == 0 ? submitButton : new Container(),
                ]
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: addDynamic,
                child:new Icon(Icons.add)
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `floatingActionButton` should be a parameter of [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html), not of `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

`floatingActionButton` should be wrapped inside the scaffold not container!
You could change it this way:

```
class _NewTaskState extends State<NewTask> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return  new Scaffold(
                body: new Container(
                    child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TaskDesc.length == 0 ? dynamicTextField : result,
                          Task.length == 0 ? submitButton : new Container(),
                        ]
                    ),
                   ),
                    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: addDynamic,
                        child:new Icon(Icons.add)
                    ),
            );
          }
        }
```